How does acoustic transducers have multiple resonances?
I am working with determining the variation of impedance of acoustic transducer with frequency. Below is the Van Dyke equivalent model of the transducer.

By analyzing this transducer equivalent model if I find the expression of first differential of the Impedance and set that equal to zero I get a fourth degree polynomial of frequency. That indicates that it has four local extremums i.e. four resonances.
In my experiment concerning the determination of variation of transducer impedance with frequency I also get four resonances, two peaks and two valleys in the frequency range 1k to 100k Hz. I understand that impedance peaks are ascociated with parallel resonance and valleys are series resonance.
My problem here is understanding this process only from the characteristics of the circuit i.e. qualitatively. I think I understand some of it. Since capacitance of C1 is lower than C0, at low frequency C1 has a higher reactance than C0 and so we have the dominant series behavior. Then as we increase frequency their reactance becomes somewhat equal and parallel behavior becomes apparent. After that I don't understand anything. Why do we again get another series resonance and after that the peak i.e. parallel resonance?
Or, could it be that I have the wrong approach from the start?
Below is the experimental setup that I've used


could you please add some details? What's the power source? What are the input and the output of the system?

First diagram is only the equivalent model of transducer I've used for understanding the working principle.  The transducer is being driven by a signal generator. By measuring voltage differences the impedance is calculated for different frequencies.
